# How to copy a file created in a python script to a remote server which needs password, using pscp?

Tags: python, ssh, putty, pscp

I need to copy many files created in a python script from local to a remote server. On the command prompt I use this line :

> "pscp c:\users\myaccount\documents\foler\file.txt name@server:/home/folder".

But this requires a password that I can enter on the command prompt.

On my python script I "import os" then :

> `cmd = "pscp local_path server_path"`
>
> `os.system(cmd)`

But I don't know how to enter the password in my script.

Thanks

Comment: Do not drive a console application to implement SFTP. Use a native Python SFTP library.

Comment: If it is possible to do boths ways, why is using a native Python SFTP library a better way?

Comment: Because with a well designed native library, like Paramiko/pysftp, you have a full control over everything. While `pscp` has a limited command-line interface.

Comment: Thanks, actually a try to use Paramiko library but I can't without the administrator rights, but it's a success with your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using paramiko package https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/

```
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
    s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    s.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",22,username=xxx,password='',timeout=4)

    sftp = s.open_sftp()
    sftp.put('/home/me/file.ext', '/remote/home/file.ext')
```

Comment: Not able to install paramiko library without administrator rights but thanks